# Create a javascript "hasValue" util method

Tags: javascript

A good javascript programmer knows well this test :

```
if (typeof(dummy) != 'undefined' && dummy != null && dummy != '') {
  // Do stuffs
}
```

In fact this test ensure that dummy variable has a value. So i tried to write this function. My tests cases are :

```
hasValue(undefined) => should returns false
hasValue(null) => should returns false
hasValue('') => should returns false
hasValue(' ') => should returns true
hasValue([]) => should returns false
hasValue({}) => should returns false
hasValue(true) => should returns true
hasValue(false) => should returns true
hasValue(0) => should returns true
hasValue(new Date()) => returns false, but should returns true ?
```

Here is the function :

```
function hasValue (v) {
  if (typeof v === 'object') {
    for (key in v) {
      if (v.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  if (v === false) {
    return true;
  }
  if (v === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return (typeof(v) != 'undefined' && v != null && v != '');
}
```

Does anyone see something wrong, or any optimization, or maybe i forgot somes cases ?

Comment: Might want to consider posting this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: These are all "values" btw. Maybe you are looking for "non-empty" values for some definition of "empty"? Also note that `typeof` is not a function.

Comment: Have you considered special constants like NaN?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: Ok, i moved this question to Code review.

Comment: I must not be a good Javascript programmer :(

Comment: Moved : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111359/create-a-javascript-hasvalue-util-method

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible util method. You're rolling up the following decisions into one function:

- Do you want `[]` to mean "the user has not selected any options, ask again" or "the user has selected no options, continue"?
- Do you want `{}` to mean "no options passed to the function" or `{}` to mean "options not passed to the function; use default options"?
- Do you want `' '` to be valid user input for a middle name but `''` to be invalid?
- Do you want `0` to be a valid user id, even though your database returns it to mean there is no user id?

The logic is domain dependent. If you are programming, say, a dashboard of user options, you could implement `UserDashboard.hasValue` that will return `false` for `[]` and the rest as stated, but this is domain-dependent logic, not some general underscore.js or jQuery or node.js core module utility function.

Even then, this would be a mess to read. If I see the line

```
if(hasValue(v)) {
   ...
 }
```

I now have to read the arcane logic in `hasValue` to figure out what possible combinations of falsey values, `[]`, `{}`, and `'`' you are allowing and disallowing. If you just need to check that `v` is not `null` write code to do that.

There are methods in various languages like `isNullOrEmpty`, which is a utility method like you stated, only its name tells you *exactly* what it does and it does not try to do everything. It probably has a more verbose name than you are thinking of. This is correct; it must, or else it's obscure what it's actually doing.

Comment: Exactly. The only `hasValue` that is good is the one that tests for `undefined` and `null` and even there I would avoid a global function.

Comment: So maybe the method should be named isEmpty ? and then change the code ? or isNotEmpty(), maybe it's easier to understand what the method should return...

Comment: @wawawoom idk is `' '` really empty? It's a string of one character so it's not empty from that point of view. What about the empty string? It's not an array so arguably it can *not* be empty so maybe this method should return false. Either way you just forced me to read the function implementation *every* time I use it, not making my life easier.

Comment: @djechlin, ok it's a problem of function naming. So in your opinion what should be the implementation of isNullOrEmpty() in javascript ?

Comment: @wawawoom I would further argue that `function doSomething(v) { if (valueThatIExpect(v) { //do something } }` is even more horrible. Why are you swallowing the fact that the client of your function used it incorrectly? That will just make it harder to debug down the road. If you want to enforce contracts then do it the right way and throw at invalid values.

Comment: `assertIsNonEmptyString(s); //throws if the value is not a string or if the string is empty` You may even make it more explicit `assertIsString(s); assertIsNonEmptyString(s.trim());` This way the client decides wheter or not the string should be trimmed. Less code doesn't mean more maintainable...

Comment: @wawawoom that's what we're trying to tell you you should not do in one method.

Comment: @wawawoom so you want something like `assertIsNonEmptyStringArrayOrObjectOrAnyBooleanOrNumber`?

Comment: sorry, that's wrong still. `assertIsNonEmptyStringArrayOrNonStringNonArrayObjectOrAnyBooleanOrNumber` ofc arrays are objects that have a `length` property among others.

Comment: @plalx, ok but why ? Sorry if i misunderstood your answers

Comment: @wawawoom also we haven't talked about whether you will accept things like `Foo = function() { }; Foo.prototype.bar = function() { };` and whether `new Foo()` is "empty" or not.

Comment: You got it, but naming like this is just a joke, so how should i name this method :)

Comment: @wawawoom you should name it `assertIsNonEmptyStringArrayOrNonStringNonArrayObjectOrAnyBooleanOrNumber`. Anything else and you're wasting my time by making me read the implementation to see whether it returns true or false for strings, empty strings, empty arrays, empty objects that are not arrays or strings, and what it does for true and false booleans and numbers.

Comment: @plalx, you're right for the new Foo(), have to think about that also.

Comment: @wawawoom to be clear, the *name* is the right name for the function, it is the *function itself* that is the joke. Which I've been trying to tell you all night.

Comment: @djechlin ok, it's clear, trying to write this method is stupid, sorry for wasting your night time.

Comment: Exactly, `hasValue(hasValue) //false` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not much but some code reduction, where your are testing for object

```
if (typeof v === 'object') {
    return Object.keys(v).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh God! help us to get rid of IE, :D

Comment: i know but some of my customers use IE8. Sad but true.

Comment: Wrong answer for empty arrays.

Comment: @djechlin, before giving such statements, kindly verify first. `Object.keys([]).length > 0` returns `false` , look at this fiddle https://jsbin.com/jutakef/edit?html,js,output